# why can polynomial assume value only finitely often

Tags: polynomials

suggest we have this set:

$$P = \{x : |p(x)| \leq 2\}$$

where $p(x)$ is polynomial with leading coefficient $(\frac{b-a}{2})^n$, where $b-a\leq4$ and it is continuous function. We know, that at any rate $P$ is the union of disjoint closed intervals $I_1, I_2, \dots$ and that $p(x)$ assumes the value 2 or -2 at each endpoint of an interval $I_j$. This implies that there are only finitely many intervals $I_1,\dots,I_t$, since $p(x)$ can assume any value only finitely often. Why?

Comment: I think we can appeal to a somewhat loose but valid argument.  A polynomial $p$ of degree $n$ has at most $n-1$ 'turns' -- I suppose properly that's points where $f'=0$.  Between these points (and before the first occurrence and after the last), $f'$ is increasing or decreasing, so attains any $a\in\mathbb R$ at most once.  Thus any value can be attained at most $n$ times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $d$ has at most $d$ roots. This follows from the division algorithm for polynomials: if $r$ is a root, then $p(x)$ factors as $(x-r)q(x)$ for some polynomial $q(x)$ of smaller degree, rinse and repeat.

Now $p(x) = a$ whenever $p(x) - a = 0$. That is, $p(x) = a$ exactly at the roots of the polynomial $q(x) = p(x) - a$, and there are only finitely many of these.

Comment: got it thanks :)